# Encrypting passwords in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, c#-4.0, passwords, salt

I'm trying to create a custom membership system in `ASP.NET MVC3`.

I know there are many free and open source providers, but I'm doing this to learn more. My question is about encrypting passwords.

Which algorithm do you suggest I use: `SHA1`, `SHA256`, `MD5`, `BCrypt`, or something else? Also, which way do you suggest to create a password salt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) if you need really strong hash. As far as generating the salt is concerned, you could use the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) class. Here's [an article](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp) that you may checkout. Just replace the SHA1 algorithm used there with BCrypt.

Comment: Thanks. Is BCrypt internally supported by .net and RNGCryptoServiceProvider?

Comment: @king.net, no, it isn't. There are .NET implementations though: http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Most of those algorithms are hashing algorithms, they don't encrypt they create a hash (checksum) and usually this is the best way to store passwords, unless you have a really good reason to want a way to restore passwords (and I don't think there are many reasons for that).

I tipically use sha256. About the salt, a random 6 or more characters string is enough. But the salt can be anything, it depends on your imagination how to generate it.