# working with BCrypt.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, c#-4.0, bcrypt, bcrypt.net

I'm working a custom membership system in `ASP.NET MVC3` ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332968/encrypting-passwords-in-asp-net-mvc-3)). And I want to use `BCrypt`. My question is about `BCrypt.net` arguments range. i.e. the *minimum* and *maximum* length of string that `BCrypt` can hash it, that *min/max* length of `salt`, and also the output string's length. Really I'm creating database now, and I want to know how to set password column in db. i.e. `nvarchar(256)` or anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BCrypt algorithm incorporates the salt into the hash so you don't need to have 2 separate columns in your database to store the hash and the password. You may checkout this [sample implementation](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx). It produces hashes of length 60 no matter how long the plain text password is.

Comment: Thanks dear @Darin :) you're a *Rescue Angelv* :D